# What is self in Python? If a second class is inheriting another class and its method, what do the 'self's indicate?

Tags: python

I'm having difficulty understanding self. Also, in the class 'anotherClass', there are two selfs. What do the two selfs indicate?

```
class myClass():
    def method1(self):
        print("myClass method1")

class anotherClass(myClass):
    def method1(self):
        myClass.method1(self)
        print("anotherClass method1")

def main():
    c = anotherClass()
    c.method1()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html - I found this page pretty informative on this subject when I was first learning about classes

Comment: Are you familiar with any other OO language? Virtually all such languages have a `this` object, which magically exists inside object methods and refers to the current object. Python simply passes this reference explicitly as a parameter instead of it magically existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self` is the instance of which the method is being called.

So if you write

```
c.method1()
```

Then `c` is passed to `method1` as its first parameter.

When you then do

```
myClass.method1(self)
```

You are not calling a method on an instance at all, but a function on the class. Self isn't set automatically, but you pass it "by hand", so it still refers to `c`.